# Is it possible to disable didSelectRowAtIndexPath in a part of row in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITablaView` in my Objective C application. I have the custom cells with a label and a `UIImageView`. I want to disable a part of the rows, to disable `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when users click on this row's part.

I want this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: you can put a button over images so it covers the cell and set tag as well if need to do some functionality later.

Comment: One way is : No need to use did select method. Just put a button on a region where u want and give an action to it.

Comment: @user3745888 : Please consider accepting the answer if it works

Answer (score 12):

Here is the simple and the most elegant solution that I can think off.

I believe you must be having a CustomCell, which holds the IBOutlet to imageView on the left side :) You can make use of `hitTest` method to solve your problem :)

In your CustomCell lets assume it to be MyTestCell class write this,

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.myImageView.frame.contains(point) {
            return nil
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
```

Where myImageView is the IBOulet of imageView on the left hand side of your cell :)

All am doing is checking where did user tap, if the touch point is within the frame of cells imageView you return nil as the view. When you return nil touch event stops propagating to its parent views and finally will never reach cell hence `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never called,

On the other hand you should handover touch to the next view and you do it simply by calling same method on its `super` iOS will eventually trace it back to cell and triggers `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Please don't add any unnecessary view to achieve your goal

Comment: nice ans plus one, but this only effects the image view area.

Comment: @vibhav :Thank you :) I believe thats what he wants :) He wants didSelectRowAtIndexPath to not get called when user taps on image on left hand side :) If you want to cover larger area then imageView rather than checking imageView contains touch point u can use the different view :)

Comment: @sandeep I have a similar problem...but I want to return nil only if user has double tapped the image...on single tap it should trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath....Can you provide some help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a *simple* trick (without the need of writing code) to solve this issue, by adding a button that covers the part that you want to disable the selection of it. Obviously, the button should not have any text or background color (it should be clear color), also make sure to add suitable constraints for making sure that is covered the wanted part of the cell.

So when tapping on the button, nothing should happen and `didselectRow` should not get called because the actual touching event should be referred to the button, not to the row.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do change the image view  `width constraints to 0`. Where you want to action is performed. As for example:

1) If you use a button that cover the image.

2) If you take a navigation bar then you there take a button and perform the action.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple trick,
Add a button on profile image part, means on red part as shown in picture (provided by you). And don't do on click on button click.

Happy Coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the button over Green area and set tag for each button. Onclick you can perform your functionality using tag. Like this

inside

```html
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

 let obj: AnyObject = self.dataList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row);
        cell?.populateCellWithData(obj, indexPath: indexPath)

cell?.destinationLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let destRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DestLabelTapped:")
        destRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        destRecognizer.delegate = self
        cell?.destinationLabel.addGestureRecognizer(destRecognizer)

}
```

and in DestLabelTapped you can peform your functionlity

**Another way** 
Just set two Tableview and scroll them side by side and one table is selectable and another is not. (don't do this)

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the tricks with buttons and other UIElements that are covering the content are not the right way to solve the target. As you will need extra manipulations with them in Storyboard, if you will need to make dynamically content, if you will work with constraints and many more situations where you will need to control your content and + the artificial cover. There are few things to do:

1. Set `UITableView` selection to `No Selection`
2. Put the second part that you want to be active in `UIView`. This UIView will be the content container.
3. Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to UIView

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectCellAction:)];
   ```
4. Add `IBAction` where you could do all you need.

   ```
   - (IBAction)selectCellAction:(id)sender
   {
      // do what you need
   }
   ```

And thats all.