# Prevent `didSelect…` for part of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

## Summary

Can a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass prevent `didSelectItemAt: indexPath` being sent to the `UICollectionViewDelegate` for taps **on some of its sub views**, but to proceed as normal for others?

## Use case

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that represents a summary of an article. For most articles, when they are tapped, we navigate through to show the article.

However, some article summaries show an inline video preview. When the video preview is tapped, we should not navigate through, but when the other areas of the article summary are tapped (the headline), we should navigate through.

I'd like the article summary cell to be able to decide whether a tap on it should be considered as a selection.

Comment: You could get the tap's point on the screen and translate it to find out whether the video view was tapped. Then, inside `didSelectItemAt:`, return before executing the rest of the code.

Comment: could you please share the screen shot of the use case,I believe you need both the way, where some of the details may not have inline video preview link.

Comment: We can differentiate two tap action by tap point on UICollectionViewCell cell. Could you please share your other special criteria for it.

Comment: One more think you can do that those details have inline preview links, you can put the preview button, so button will be first responder and it will not navigate to the next viewcontroller.

Comment: @benjohn : No need to add any thing to existing cell no tap gesture, no button nothing. You can solve it with a elegant usage of `hitTest` take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137703/is-it-possible-to-disable-didselectrowatindexpath-in-a-part-of-row-in-uitablevie/41137930#41137930 Similar issue solved with `hitTest` :) feel free to upvote though if it helped :)

Comment: Hi @SandeepBhandari, thanks for the comment, suggestion and link. I think in this situation that the `hitTest` override approach would have quite low discoverability for future programmers making changes or diagnosing issues. We are actually using `hitTest` override currently (in a more convoluted way) and it's this that I want to improve. I have used `hitTest` before to implement a circular boarder on a control, so while I'm familiar with it, I feel the gesture recogniser approach is a better solution in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. You have to add `tapGestureRecogniser` on those subviews of cell on which you don't want delegate to get called.
> 2. `tapGestureRecogniser` selector method will get called when you will tap on those subview and gesture will not get passed to delegate.

Comment: I would also suggest this approach rather than subclassing. You should keep your code where it happens, rather than hiding it in a subclass thus adding complexity.

Comment: Super – thank you. While there is an existing sub class, I also agree a gesture recogniser is preferable to overriding `hitTest`.. It's a lot more "expected" and easier to for a future developer to find or diagnose. The current solution uses a `hitTest` override and I was looking for a more discoverable alternative. It also composes more flexibly than putting the behaviour in a sub class.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to attach `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view and monitor taps from it:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, MyCellDelegate {

    var dataSource: [Article] = []

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ArticleCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.article = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func articleDidTap(_ article: Article) {
        // do what you need
    }

}



// your data model
struct Article {}


protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func articleDidTap(_ article: Article)
}


class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var article: Article! {
        didSet {
            // update your views here
        }
    }
    weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyCell.tap)))
    }

    @objc func tap() {
        delegate?.articleDidTap(article)
    }

}
```

This should work since your video view should overlap root view and prevent receiving taps from gesture recognizer.